# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/SP500.html'

Tags: python, ioerror

I installed a package finsymbols in python by

```
pip install finsymbols
```

the installation went fine.
But when I tried to work with that, there was an error saying that permission denied. The code I have tried is

```
>>>import finsymbols
>>>sp500 = finsymbols.get_sp500_symbols()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/symbols.py", line 8, in get_sp500_symbols
    page_html = wiki_html('List_of_S%26P_500_companies', 'SP500.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/symbol_helper.py", line 94, in wiki_html
    save_file(file_path, wiki_html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/symbol_helper.py", line 39, in save_file
    saved_file = open(file_path, "w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/SP500.html'
```

can anyone help me in solving this ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you do not have write access to the finsymbols package folder.

Give the folder write access and try again:

```
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols
```

If you do not want to give access to that folder, run your python as a root user.

Comment: Thank you . earlier I tried sudo chmod +w /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/finsymbols/SP500.html . But it did not work. Is it something like I can give permissions to modify the folders only ??

Comment: Yes. Permission change only applied to the folder. Now if you add a file in that folder, you will see that the owner of the file you added is your current user. So each file still has its own permission. If you want to change all files inside that folder, you can add the -R option when running chmod to recursively update permissions to all files and folders inside.

Comment: Thank you very much. that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

The better approach would be to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)  This would have allowed you to install any package without requiring elevated permissions.

You can get a quick guide by visiting
https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/